# Movie about encountering blue alien

Tags: identify-this-movie, science-fiction

I watched this movie around early 2000's. It's in English.

There are a group of people researching something (not really sure maybe a fallen object from space) in the ocean. They sent some kind of robot to investigate it. But they failed because water pressure destroy the robot. Another scene I remember is a man is taken to a chamber of glowing light and communicating? with the alien. I think the alien in a form of a fish/stingray

Comment: This description is great - Its just funny that it almost lines up perfectly with both movies suggested below.  I believe the one you are looking for is The Abyss though.

Comment: @Mumford451 and if it's not The Abyss, OP should see it immediately. ...actually, even if it is, it should be watched again ASAP!

Comment: A great movie indeed

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It could be [The Abyss (1989)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0096754/?ref_=nv_sr_1).

Here is a picture of the stingray alien:

[image]

Another shot of the blue, stingray-like underwater aliens:
[image]

Here is a shot of Ed Harris, standing in the undwerwater chamber and communicating with the aliens:
[image]

You can watch the complete movie here (quality is not the best, the picture is intentionally distorted to avoid deletion from Youtube due to copyright reasons):

Near the end of the movie, starting ca. at the 2:04:00 mark, the underwater aliens save Ed Harris' character and bring him to a room in their submerged base/ship. In that room Harris communicates with the aliens.

There are several submersibles in the movie. There is a scene in the movie where after a prolonged underwater duel between two submersibles, one is manned by Ed Harris and Mastrantonio, the other is manned by the mad Navy Seal (played by Michael Biehn), **the good guys manage to push the crazy SEAL's damaged submersible into the abyss, and after a short descent the enormous water pressure pulverizes the submersible. The desctruction of the submersible starts ca. at the 1:35:14 mark**.

> "Bud fights Coffey but Coffey escapes in a mini-sub with the primed
>   warhead, and Bud and Lindsay give chase in the other sub. Coffey is
>   able to launch the warhead into the trench, but his sub is damaged and
>   drifts over the edge of the trough, and he is crushed **when the sub
>   implodes from high pressures.**"

You can read a detailed plot description for the movie on Wikipedia here:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Abyss

Comment: This is the one. I remember the stingray looking alien.

Answer (score 4):

Not sure if this one is what you're looking for. The name of the movie is **Sphere**, aired in 1998 and lead by Sharon Stone and Dustin Hoffman. The plot: A spaceship is discovered under three hundred years' worth of coral growth at the bottom of the ocean, and a team goes down to investigate.

[Sphere (1998) IMDb](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0120184/videoplayer/vi797245721?ref_=tt_ov_vi)

[image: Sphere]